# Multiple android connection via Bluetooth

Tags: android, networking, bluetooth

I am doing a project on connection of multiple Android mobiles via Bluetooth.
Is it possible to connect multiple android phones via Bluetooth???? How many android mobiles can chat on the Blutooth chat application????????

Comment: have you got some code to help me to connect multiple android mobile like one to many connection for android via bluetooth .Give any help if you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes - the limit is typically set by the manufacturer / make / model of the device, 3 is typical.

Comment: Thank you...How to access internet from one mobile to another mobile?